# How to create a full width HTML table with borders?

Tags: html, css

**Current HTML:**

```html
    <section class="Product-Info">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Product Infromation</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Product Name:</th>
          <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Product Description:</th>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
```

**Desired:**

[image: Desired output]

**Question:**

How can I add borders and width to my current HTML with CSS as the desired outcome?

**What I have tried**

I have tried the following css:

```
  table {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

This just puts a border around the table. How can I add it same as desired too?

Comment: Also your `table` is invalid HTML...`<th>Product Name:</th>` should be `<td>Product Name:</td>` and so on.

Comment: @Paulie_D how come? Left is the title and right is the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* if you don't add this line you will see "double" borders */
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100vw;
}

th{
color: white;
background-color: blue;
}

td{
background-color: white;
width: 70%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section class="Product-Info">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Product Infromation</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name:</th>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Description:</th>
      <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Heres, your snippet!

Answer (score 1):

hope it help you

```css
section {
width:100wh;

}
table{
width:100%
}
```

```html
<section class="Product-Info">
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Product Infromation</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product Name:</td>
          <td >Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td  > Product Description:</td>
          <td  >Description</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
```

Comment: width should be 100vh, not 100wh

Answer (score 1):

Fairly easy, in your example you just have to apply the desired background colour to the table header cells (th), like so:

```css
    th {
    background: darkblue;
    color: white; /* Assuming you don't want black text on dark blue. */ 
    }
```

For the standard border around the table cells to disappear you have to simply collapse the border on the main table element, like so:

```css
    table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

With that set you can now apply any border styling you want to your table, in any thickness, colour and style you want.

Answer (score 1):

Extra information (The "copy-paste" snippet under @Random-COSMOS answer).

Table is `block-level` element

> "A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the
>   full width available. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp"

Set any width you want to the table (400px or 30%) ==> `100%` in your case (100% of its parent).

`<table style="width: 100%;">`

To specify table borders in CSS, use the border property.

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Out of topic - Accessible tables**

For Web Accessibility => Add relationship between header and data cells (scope="row" / scope="col").
Full article: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/two-headers/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2">Product Infromation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Product Name:</th>
    <td>Some Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Product Description:</th>
    <td>Some Description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the following:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Product-Info > table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

.Product-Info tr > *:first-child {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.w-25 {
  width: 25% !important;
  max-width: 25% !important;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="Product-Info">
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col class="w-25 blue">
      <col class="">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Product Infromation</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">Product Name:</th>
      <td class="text-center">Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">Product Description:</th>
      <td class="text-center">Description</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply this:

```css
table {
border-collapse: collapse; /* if you don't add this line you will see "double" borders */
border: 1px solid black;
}

table th,
table td {
text-align: left;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

demo here https://jsfiddle.net/3hpks1mL/